# Jenkins/GitLab pipeline email sending warning and creating Jenkins users

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, cd

I have been digging trying to figure out the warning I am getting in the pipeline that we have. It was done by a contractor, now gone. I took over the CI/CD tools, Jenkins, GitLab and Chef.

I constantly see a warning message, that user is not found, but sending email anyway. "xxx.xxx@company.com is not a recognized user, but sending mail anyway xxx.xxx@company.com"

Until I really started to dig into this, I didn't realize that this is causing 2 user auto-added entries into Jenkins.

As other threads I have found on stackoverflow, we have our security realm set to Active Directory, we have a 4 digit code, expanding to 8 digits for the user ID, and it does not match our email addresses of first.last@company.com.

I was in the group back in 2017 when we started implementing these tools, so I have multiple Jenkins accounts, one is firstname.lastname and is confirmed as well as the A/D user ID, so when I run the pipeline, it finds me and no warning/error. When someone that is newer than I, only has an A/D account ID, they get the error and the erroneous accounts are created. first.last and firstlast for the names of the accounts.

Is there anyway to look at the user ID, that is the same in GitLab and Jenkins rather than Email address for the pipeline? Or can I have the warning message but not auto-create the users in Jenkins?

Comment: please format your question properly. use line break and sections. add a code example and error message if possible.

Comment: Thank you Roy, hopefully this is better.